# Find the value of integration following : $\int x^2\sqrt{x^2+1}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

Find the value of integration following :
$$\int x^2\sqrt{x^2+1} dx$$

Comment: Two notes - please use MathJax for math expressions. Please share your thoughts. What have you tried?

Comment: Add and subtract 1, then do a trig sub.

Comment: @CameronWilliams: evn if relvnt I'm nt sure such hints hlpful.

Answer (score 4):

Let $x=\sinh(t)$ and $dx=\cosh(t) \,dt$. So, $$I=\int x^2\sqrt{x^2+1}\ dx=\int \sinh^2(t)\cosh^2(t)\,dt=\frac 14 \int \sinh^2(2t)\,dt=\frac 18 \int (\cosh(4t)-1)\,dt$$ $$I=\frac 1{32}\sinh(4t)-\frac t8+C$$

Comment: By far the slickest solution. +1

Comment: @zz20s. Thank you ! May I confess that, when I see $\sqrt{1+x^2}$, I immediately think about $x=\sinh(t)$ ? Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x=\tan u$ and $dx= \sec^2u du$

$\displaystyle\int x^2\sqrt{x^2+1} dx=\int \tan^2 u\sqrt{\tan^2 u+1} \sec^2 u du=\int (\tan^2 u \sec^3 u )du=\int (1-\sec^2 u)(\sec^3 u)du=\int (\sec^3 u-\sec^5 u )du$

Now, use the reduction formula for $\displaystyle\int \sec^m u du=\frac{\sec^{m-2}u \tan u}{m-1}+\frac{m-2}{m-1}\int \sec^{m-2}udu$.

Answer (score 0):

You can alternately apply the following tranform:

Let,
$$x=\frac{1}{2}\Big(t-\frac{1}{t}\Big)$$
So,
$$dx=\frac{1}{2}\Big(1+\frac{1}{t^2}\Big)dt$$
and
$$\sqrt{x^2+1}=\Big(t+\frac{1}{t}\Big)$$
Thus, your integral becomes:
$$I=\int\frac{1}{4}\Big(t-\frac{1}{t}\Big)^2\frac{1}{2}\Big(1+\frac{1}{t^2}\Big)\Big(t+\frac{1}{t}\Big)dt$$ which can be easily-though perhaps somewhat tediously-evaluated.

Comment: Not so tedious; the integrand is just $\frac{1}{16 t^5}+\frac{t^3}{16}-\frac{1}{8 t}$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Ah, as I said "somewhat" tedious. It does look intimidating. :-) Btw Your answer is the best sir.. +1

Answer (score -2):

$$
\frac{1}{4}(x^2+1)^{\frac{3}{2}}-\frac{x}{8}\sqrt{x^2+1}-\frac{1}{8}\mathrm{arcsinh}(x)
$$
Differentiating the above will give you $x^2\sqrt{x^2+1}$, proving it is indeed the antiderivative.

Comment: How does one divine this expression just by looking at the integral?

Comment: Who says I only looked at the integral? I worked it out. I just don't have time (at least not now) to write down the whole computation. I posted the answer in case OP was primarily interested in the end result. Not sure why that's worth a downvote, as my answer could be helpful...

Comment: In terms of the method of finding the integral, your answer is entirely useless. There is nothing to indicate how you went about your computation.